# Userfeedback after file was uploaded to library

Tags: javascript, event-receivers, file-upload, user-controls

I need to print out a feedback after a file was uploaded to a DocLib. I tried several things over the event receiver (add statusbar as a control or a clientscript) but everything faild.

I´m a bit frustrated. I can set the statusbar via ECMA/Javascript but I can´t listen on the ItemAdded event. I already found the trick to do this over a special webpart but its not the best way to add a webpart everytime. Could you give me another way or solution for that?

Maybe there is another way to check whether a file was uploaded (without the Event Receiver)?!

Thank for all effort!

Answer (score 0):

**[I don't have much experience on JQuery, SPServices and List Service etc.]**

The solution I see it is making an InfoPath form for taking and printing feedback, so after the OOB Upload Document WebPart uploads the file to document library... It should redirect the page to this InfoPath form where you can create a view and set that view as default for Print Form [available in Form Options]

[Redirect after File Upload in Document Library](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/169a82fa-ad28-404c-b22b-53bc2d8ecb49), you can take the redirection part from this thread!

Let me know if you are stuck anywhere!